# Looping through a list to pass several functions R

Tags: r, list

I have a complex script to get some results in a data frame format. The script includes two different functions as you can see below.

```
nSNP=(mean(DF$NSNP[DF$KB>=1000 & DF$KB<=1100]))*0.1
data.n = apply(data.frame(seq(0,249900000,100000), seq(100000,250000000,100000)), MARGIN=1,
                function(x,y,z,a) poisson.roh_island(DF, 1, x[1], x[2]))
data.p = apply(data.frame(seq(0,249900000,100000), seq(100000,250000000,100000)), MARGIN=1,
                function(x,y,z,a) roh_island(DF, 1, x[1], x[2]))
av<-mean(data.n)
pval<-ppois(data.n,lambda=av,lower=FALSE)
x<-seq(1:2500)
pos<-(x*1e+05)
len<-rep(0.1,2500)
nsnp<-rep(nSNP,2500)
prop<-data.p*100
data<-data.frame(cbind(x,data.n,prop,pos,len,nsnp,pval))
data.p<-subset(data,data$pval<=2e-05)
data.re<-data.p %>% group_by(new=cumsum(c(1,diff(x)!=1))) %>% 
  summarise(pos1=min(pos),pos2=max(pos),len=sum(len),nsnp=sum(nsnp),n.ind=mean(data.n),per.ind=mean(prop))
Chr<-rep(1,length(data.re$pos1))
DF.i<-data.frame(cbind(Chr,data.re))
```

I don’t have problems to run it when having a single Data Frame (DF in the script). However I need to pass this code to all the elements (data frames) of a particular list. All the different DFs within the list have the same structure and columns (DF$NSNP and DF$KB also included of course). The outcomes need to be storage in a different list. Here is where problems start, I tried to use the apply family to loop over the list with any success. Please could you help me?

Also, if you see any easy boosts in efficiency please feel free to chime in! Thanks =)

Comment: did you try `lapply` ?

Comment: Yeah, did, in different possitions hahaha but It didnt work.

Comment: You need to share a sample of `input` and the `function` to which you intend to pass the input. I am pretty sure this issue can be easily solved.

Comment: The function is what you see in the code I shared.... instead of DF (single data frame) I need to pass all this code to a list with several DF. The imput is really very long to be shared here. I will try to create a short versión an update the question.

Comment: ideally using `lapply` it should be something like: `lapply(list_of_df,someFunc)` where `someFunc` is `someFunc<-function(DF){ **code you posted** }`. Just try to run the code for just 2 data.frame's at first. Maybe the code is throwing error for some input in the data.frame not accounted for.

Comment: Also, where is the call for `data.n` and `data.p` getting the `x[1]` & `x[2]` from?

Comment: From seq(0,249900000,100000), and seq(100000,250000000,100000). This is the mother function:
roh_island<-function(pop,chr,p1,p2){
  names(pop)<-tolower(names(pop))
  a<-pop[pop$chr==chr,]
  island<-subset(a,pos1<=p1 & pos2>=p2)
  n<-length(unique(island$iid))/length(unique(pop$iid))
  return(n)
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153101/discussion-between-tushar-and-cebs).

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much. I just create a function with everything in it and the the lapplay